# r shiny tags$video not showing video

Tags: r, video, shiny

I want to play an mp4 video in a shiny output. It plays fine on my computer when I double click on the file name. I copied the file to the www folder below the main app folder. I have tried variations on the following code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(debug = TRUE),
  mainPanel(
    "video test",
    uiOutput('ozoneVideo'), id = "mainPanel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ozoneVideo <- renderUI({
   h6("ozone video", tags$video(src = "MesaCountyOzone2017_07_10.mp4",  type = "video/mp4", width = "1080px", height = "480px", controls = "controls", autoplay = NA))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The web page that is generated shows the text elements (video test, ozone video) and horizontal bar with a video play button and the word "Error" with no explanation. No error appears in the javascript console.

When I add www/ to the filename, the javascript console has an error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and a url of `http://127.0.0.1:4817/www/MesaCountyOzone2017_07_10.mp4`

Any help clarifying this greatly appreciated!

Update: July 11, 2017. 
I am now pretty sure this is a problem with Safari. I run the app with run external chosen. The web page that opens up in Safari has an error message in the video control section. If I copy the url and past to a Chrome web page, the video plays fine.

So my question is now what do I do to make this play in Safari???

Comment: Seems to look ok. What about when you set controls to `NA`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference. But I should have posted the console output in my original post. The ERROR message is below (it seems to be common but I couldn't find a fix that worked for me. I'm running on a mac with output to Safari, R ver 3.3.4, shiny version 1.0.3.9001 (from GitHub))

`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4817
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer`